# ggplot: how to choose the "proper" colors relating on a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Suppose I have a simple dataframe to plot, in which I have to color the points related to the measure contained in a column. So, if I have:

```
dataframe
# X1            X2     pop
# 1  -0.11092652 -1.955598e-09  448053
# 2  -0.09999865 -2.310067e-10  418231
# 3  -0.05944755 -3.475013e-09  448473
# 4   0.51378848  1.631781e-09  119548
# 5   0.09438223 -9.606475e-10  323288
# 6   0.19349045  6.074025e-10  203153
# 7   0.06685609  3.210156e-10  208339
# 8  -0.10915456 -1.407190e-09  429178
# 9  -0.10348100 -1.401948e-09 1218038
# 10 -0.08607617 -7.356602e-10  383018
# 11  1.00343465 -2.423237e-08  209550
# 12 -0.05839148  1.503955e-09  287042
# 13 -0.09960163  2.167945e-10  973129
# 14 -0.05793417  2.510107e-09  187249
# 15  0.02191610  2.479708e-09  915225
# 16  0.48877872  1.338346e-08  462999
# 17 -0.10289556  1.472368e-09 1108776
# 18 -0.10316414  2.933469e-10  402422
# 19 -0.09545279 -2.926035e-10  274035
# 20 -0.06111044  3.464014e-09  230749
```

and I use ggplot in the following way:

```
ggplot(dataframe) +
  ggtitle("Somehow useful spatialization")+  # Electricity / Gas
  geom_point(aes(dataframe$X1, dataframe$X2), color = dataframe$pop, size=2 ) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4)))+
  xlab("X")+ylab("Y")
```

I obtain something like:
[image]

that is a possible representaion.
Neverthless, suppose that I want the points colored such to represent the column `pop`, i.e., having colors from (for example) light orange, passing for dark red and then black. How can I "scale" the column `pop` to obtain such graphics?

EDIT:

```
> dput(dataframe)
structure(list(X1 = c(-0.110926520419347, -0.0999986452719714, 
-0.0594475526112884, 0.513788479303472, 0.0943822277852107, 0.193490454204271, 
0.0668560854540437, -0.109154563987586, -0.103480996064617, -0.0860761723229372, 
1.00343465471568, -0.0583914756527933, -0.0996016272609995, -0.0579341671474729, 
0.0219161022704227, 0.488778719096658, -0.102895564162661, -0.103164140322136, 
-0.0954527927249849, -0.0611104428640883), X2 = c(-1.9555978205951e-09, 
-2.31006712207053e-10, -3.47501251356368e-09, 1.63178106438806e-09, 
-9.60647459243156e-10, 6.07402512804044e-10, 3.21015629676789e-10, 
-1.40718981687972e-09, -1.40194842954735e-09, -7.35660154466167e-10, 
-2.423237202138e-08, 1.50395541775022e-09, 2.16794489937917e-10, 
2.51010717100061e-09, 2.47970820013341e-09, 1.33834570208731e-08, 
1.47236816671351e-09, 2.93346922578509e-10, -2.92603459149485e-10, 
3.46401369936372e-09), pop = c(448053L, 418231L, 448473L, 119548L, 
323288L, 203153L, 208339L, 429178L, 1218038L, 383018L, 209550L, 
287042L, 973129L, 187249L, 915225L, 462999L, 1108776L, 402422L, 
274035L, 230749L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "pop"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you can add the `dput()` of your dataframe, we can use the data ourselves. (run `dput(dataframe)` and put the output in your question) At first glance it it might have to do with where you add color. What happens if you use: `geom_point(aes(x = X1, y = X2, color = pop), size=2 ) +` instead of your geom_point line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ggplot you can add your aesthetics (aes) in your inital ggplot call. Since you're already telling ggplot where the data is (in `dataframe`), you can refer to the variables directly by their name (without `dataframe$`). Now for the color to be a scale it needs to be called as a aesthetic, inside the `aes()` call, and not as a static value. Once it is added as an aesthetic, we can customize how it reacts by adding a `scale`. Taking this all into account gives us the following code:

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = X1, y = X2, color = pop)) +
  ggtitle("Somehow useful spatialization")+  # Electricity / Gas
  geom_point(size=2) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4))) +
  xlab("X")+ylab("Y") +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "red", high = "black", midpoint = mean(dataframe$pop))
```

This code gives the following graph. The colors could be further adjusted by playing around with the `scale_color_gradient2` part. (Why green as `low` gives a better orange than actually choosing orange as the `low` color is beyond me, I just ended up there by coincidence)

[image: The resulting graph]

Comment: Thanks Marijn! Can I also ask you how to modify the legend "pop"?

Comment: If you have a specific problem you want to get fixed in the legend you should probably make another question. If it just general tweaking you could check out the ggplot2 documentation over on: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ Or specifically for the legend: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guides.html or http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html

Comment: I have solved just fixing (in this case) "theNameIwant <- pop" and doing the same as i did before.